# Advanced greek typing

Tags: linux, keyboard, greek

I often use Greek letters in my LaTeX documents. To avoid unreadable source files with `\alpha`, `\phi`, etc., I use Unicode and Greek letters directly. This is easy to configure with commands like

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\alpha}
```

For typing, I switch between english and Greek keyboard layouts.

Both LaTeX and Unicode recognizes variants for a few Greek letters

> U+03C6 φ GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI: `\varphi` in LaTeX
>
> U+03D5 ϕ GREEK PHI SYMBOL: `\phi` in LaTeX
>
> U+03B5 ε GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON: `\varepsilon` in LaTeX
>
> U+03F5 ϵ GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL: `\epsilon` in LaTeX

Although, my Greek layout does not proposes multiple variants for these letters.

Does someone know an appropriate way to input a specific variant of these Greek letters?

Comment: Adapt your keyboard layout so it produces all variants? For example with `xmodmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a satisfactory solution. As suggested by dirkt the idea is to customize the keyboard layout, but I used the compose key. I just had to add the entry in my `.XCompose` file:

```
<Multi_key> <Greek_sigma> : "ς" U03C2 # Final sigma; \varsigma in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_beta> : "ϐ" U03D0 # Curled beta
<Multi_key> <Greek_theta> : "ϑ" U03D1 # Script Theta; \vartheta in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_phi> : "ϕ" U03D5 # Phi symbol; \phi in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_pi> : "ϖ" U03D6 # Omega Pi; \varpi in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_gamma> : "Ϝ" U03DC # Digamma; \digamma in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_kappa> : "ϰ" U03D0 # Scpipt Kappa; \varkappa in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_rho> : "ϱ" U03D1 # Tailed Rho; \varrho in LaTeX
<Multi_key> <Greek_epsilon> : "ϵ" U03F5 # Lunate Epsilon; \epsilon in LaTeX
```

When the Greek layout is on, I just type `CapsLock+f` to produce ϕ instead of φ. Easy! (My Compose key is mapped on `CapsLock`.)